# Python: Post json to MySql Database

Tags: python, mysql, json

I'm a bit at a loss for how to just push my json data to MySql. I have the cursor. Do I need to create a table first? Is there a method to simply push my json data straight in?

```
with open("trades.json") as f:
    trades_data = json.load(f)

trades_data = reconfigure_data(trades_data)

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user=os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_USER'),
    password=os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_USER_PASS',
    database='trades')
)

cursor = db.cursor()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the syntax that works:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
# create table on database
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `objectid` VARCHAR(100), `type` VARCHAR(5), `ownerid` VARCHAR(100), `color` VARCHAR(15), `shape` VARCHAR(15), `size` VARCHAR(15), PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );"
print(sql)
cursor.execute(sql)

with open("trades.json") as f:
    trades_data = json.load(f)

    for trade in trades_data:
        for right in trade['rights']:
            sql = f"INSERT INTO test (objectid, type, ownerid, color, shape, size)     VALUES ('{trade['objectid']}', '{trade['type']}', '{trade['ownerid']}', '{right['color']}', '{right['shape']}', '{right['size']}' )"
           
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()
```